# bash: /usr/bin/express: /usr/bin/nodejs: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, express

i am trying to make template using this command -

```
express -e project-name
```

in node_modules - express and express-generator are both installed, i checked.

Also `express --help` does not work and writes same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, i fixed this and if somebody ever will have this question here is answer:

1. delete node and reinstall it with npm globally.
2. run all of these 3 commands in terminal

   ```
   npm set prefix ~/.npm
   PATH="$HOME/.npm/bin:$PATH"
   PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
   ```
3. next install

   ```
   npm install -g express
   npm install -g express-generator
   ```